# Laravel 10 игнорирует "->where"

Tags: laravel

Дано:

```php
$items = Item::query()
            ->where('item_docs_id', '=', $itemDoc)
            ->when(RequestFacade::input('search'), function($query, $search) {
                $query->where('article', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
                      ->orWhere('name_ru', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
```

Т.е. есть модель, из которой мы берём данные для странички выборки документа, т.е. связь:

```
->where('item_docs_id', '=', $itemDoc)
```

Если производить поиск, пример по `article`:

```
->where('article', 'like', '%' . $search . '%')
```

Ищет по этому документу, без проблем.
Но если:

```
->orWhere('name_ru', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
```

то игнорирует:

```
->where('item_docs_id', '=', $itemDoc)
```

Вопрос, почему он игнорирует?
Спасибо!

Comment: Отдебажте (посмотрите, какой запрос в итоге формируется) через `barryvdh/laravel-debugbar` или Telescope.

Comment: Можно аросто использовать `->toSql()` для просмотра итогового запроса.

Comment: Вот запрос:select
  count(*) as aggregate
from
  "items"
where
  "item_docs_id" = '13'
  and "article" :: text like '%РЕМЕНЬ ГЕНЕРА%'
  or "name_ru" :: text like '%РЕМЕНЬ ГЕНЕРА%'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помог такой запрос, но он большой, может есть что то элегантнее:

```html
$items = Item::query()
            ->where('item_docs_id', '=', $itemDoc)
            ->when(RequestFacade::input('search'), function($query, $search) {
                $query->where('article', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
            })
            ->orWhere('item_docs_id', '=', $itemDoc)
            ->when(RequestFacade::input('search'), function($query, $search) {
                $query->where('name_ru', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
            })
            ->select('id', 'item_docs_id','article', 'brand', 'name_ru', 'name_en', 'purchase_price_original', 'amount', 'file_place')
            ->paginate(10)->withQueryString();
```

Comment: лучше будет вам либо новый вопрос задать, либо дополнить существующий.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так, скорее всего неправильно группируются условия в конечном запросе (`WHERE condition AND condition2 OR condition3` вместо `WHERE condition AND (condition2 OR condition3)`)

```
 $items = Item::query()
         ->where('item_docs_id', '=', $itemDoc)
         ->when(RequestFacade::input('search'), function ($query, $search) {
             $query->where(function ($q) use ($search) {
                 $q
                     ->where('article', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
                     ->orWhere('name_ru', 'like', '%'.$search.'%');
             });
         });
```

Comment: Добавил $search: (function ($q, $search)  . Но не помогло. Но пишет ошибку: ArgumentCountError
PHP 8.2.4
10.1.1
Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\Stock\ItemListController::App\Http\Controllers\Stock\{closure}(), 1 passed in /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php on line 292 and exactly 2

Comment: @Igor добавлять так надо -> `$query->where(function ($q) use ($search) {`

Comment: @Igor пардон, забыл про параметр, дополнил код в ответе